# A Question of integration based on partial fraction but my question is why does it work?

Tags: integration

Integrate 
$$
    \frac{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)}{(x-4)(x-5)(x-6)}
$$
Now in this problem we divide it into 
$$
    \frac{A}{x-4}+\frac{B}{x-5}+\frac{C}{x-6}+1
$$
My question is: even if we do not consider $+1$ the values of A B and C comes the same so what does that mean? Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

If you have
$$\frac{A}{x-4}+\frac{B}{x-5}+\frac{C}{x-6}\tag{*}$$
it will simplify to something of the form
$$\frac{Rx^2+Sx+T}{(x-4)(x-5)(x-6)}$$
with a **quadratic** in the numerator. But your
integrand has a **cubic** in the numerator, so cannot be written
in the form (*).

Comment: +1 ensures coefficient of x in the denominator matches with that of the numerator.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)}{(x-4)(x-5)(x-6)}=A/(x-4)+B/(x-5)+C/(x-6)+1$$

is the correct form. Note that the degree of both top and bottom is the same so we first divide to get a $1$ as the quotient.

If you do not include a $+1$ on the RHS then as $x$ approached infinity, the right side approaches $0$ while the left side approaches $1$

Note that with the wrong form you may still find A, B, C but the answer is wrong.